Interpretation of $f(x;c\theta)$
I am trying to understand the meaning of the notation $f(x;c\theta)$, where $c$ is known constant. For example, assume the random variable $X$ is Poisson-distributed. When we write $f_X(x;2\theta)$, are we simply implying that $X \sim \operatorname{Poission}(2\theta)$? Or do we hold that $f_X(x;\theta) = f_X(x)$ and take $f(x;2\theta)$ to denote the expression you get when you substitute every occurrence of the symbol $\theta$ in $f_X(x)$ with $2\theta$?
In other words, given that
$$X \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(2\theta)$$
which of the following statements is true?
$$f_X(x;2\theta) = \frac{(2\theta)^xe^{-2\theta}}{x!} \tag{1}$$
$$f_X(x;2\theta) = \frac{(2(2\theta))^xe^{-2(2\theta)}}{x!} \tag{2}$$

The first statement is true.
